# Select multiple images from a grid of thumbnail images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, forms

I have grid of thumbnail images on a form, and I would like for the user to be able to select multiple images, and have their selection submitted with the form.

My requirements are:

- Single click to select the image, and selection is fed back to user, e.g by changing the border.
- Degrade gracefully to just html, and still work.
- Cross browser/device support (needs to work on ipad for example)

Can all my requirements be satisfied?

thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `Degrade gracefully to just html, and still work.`??

Comment: Might not be exactly what you're looking for, but this tute might be of use: http://blogs.sitepoint.com/controlling-lists-with-jquery/

Comment: @ITroubs - I was anticipating a javascript solution, but wanted to be clear that the solution can not depend on javascript in order to function. I accept that a changing border with just HTML is not possible.

Comment: if you realy want it to work without javascript and only plain HTML then you wil have to use checkboxes right next or on top (depends on your css styling) of your images so the user can check these.

Comment: you could do it like this: thumbnail and on top or right next to it you put your checkbox. then via jquery you hide the checkboxes and attach your click events to the thumbnails that check and uncheck the checkboxes. thus you have support for browsers supporting jquery and not supporting any javascript at all. if the browser doesn't support the js then the checkboxes won't be hidden and the checkboxes are usable as usual. if the browser does then they will be hidden and the fancy js actions will be used instead.

Comment: @ITroubs - That's what I was thinking, but then I would like to be able to layer javascript on top of this for a more polished feel (changing borders for selected images)

Comment: like i said. image. checkbox next to image. in your `$(document).lad(function(){...});` you do this `$(".checkbox").hide();` then `$(".image").click(function(){doyourstuff;});`

Comment: @ITroubs - My previous comment was in reply to your comment starting "if you realy want it to work" they got a bit out of sync. Do you want to post the above as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this: thumbnail and on top or right next to it you put your checkbox. Then via jquery you hide the checkboxes and attach your click events to the thumbnails that check and uncheck the checkboxes. thus you have support for browsers supporting jquery and not supporting any javascript at all. if the browser doesn't support the js then the checkboxes won't be hidden and the checkboxes are usable as usual. if the browser does then they will be hidden and the fancy js actions will be used instead.

for example:

```
<div id="container1" class="container">
    <img>
    <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="foo1"/>
</div>
<div id="container2" class="container">
    <img>
    <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="foo1"/>
</div>

$(document).lad(function(){
    $(".container .cbox").hide();
    $(".container img").click(function(){
        //do the stuff you need to do like
       var $checkbox = $(this).parent().find(".cbox");
       $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
    });
});
```

try it out. this may work but i give no guaranty.

Answer (score 1):

For a javascript approach [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2REAB/):

**Markup:**

```
<div>
    <img data-id="1" src="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="images[ ]" />
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$('img').live('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('selected');

    if($this.hasClass('selected'))
        $this.next(':hidden').val($this.data('id'))
    else
        $this.next(':hidden').val('');
});
```

Comment: If this approach was used you wouldn't need to have an input per image, just one would suffice.

Comment: Thanks Josiah, but no good if they have JS turned off. Perhaps it could be adapted to use check boxes instead of inputs.

Comment: btw live() compared to delegate() is verry verry bad! read here: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/08/bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-function.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want such fancy stuff as changing the border color of selected thumbnails, you will need javascript to do it. Especially if you need cross browser support.

As for when javascript is turned off, which I assume, is what you meant in your second point, I'd just use checkboxes for the thumbnails and let the user select what he/she needs.